# Codeigniter - How to understand how much controllers and models should I create?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have already read [Codeigniter Routing - Using it too much?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384063/codeigniter-routing-using-it-too-much).

But still I can't understand how many controllers and models should I use in my system.

**Question 01**

I am creating shopping cart system.

I have created 3 controllers and models so far.

1. Product Controller and Model
2. Admin Controller and Model
3. Pages Controller and Model (Maintain pages like about us, contact us)
4. User Controller and Model

Should I have controller like Shopping cart or is it better to write those codes in Product Controller also?

For login purposes should I create Controller called Login or should I use already created Admin and User Controller?

**And I have this question also.**

I have a function name `display_product_list()` in product model. It is used to display products in front end.

I have to display product list on admin panel also. So should I create `display_product_list()` in admin model also? Or **it it better just load product model to Admin controller**?

**Question 02**

If you want to create a basic shopping cart system (Like CMS - that means user can add products, users, etc). Assume that PayPal and pay on delivery methods are avalable.

What are controllers you create? And What are models you create?

Comment: You should create models and controllers around _entities_ in your application. A _product_ is an entity. A _cart_ is an entity. A cart has items, so _cart item_ is an entity. The models representing these entities should then have methods that perform actions on those items, i.e. `$cart->addItem($item)`. When you build your application this way, it’s much easier to follow and reason about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your application workflow and which type of functionality you have to do in your web app.

Generally, controllers depend on a number of modules and sub-modules in the Web application.

basic **modules** of shopping cart system are:

1. Catalog Management
2. User accounts(customers/admin/sellers(for multi seller system))
3. Products (add/update/delete/browsing)
4. Manage cart
5. Checkout and payment(Online/COD)
6. Shipping Management(delivery of order and tracking)
7. Order management
8. Analytics & Reports generation
9. SEO

And your question is regarding `**display_product_list()**`:

If this function does the same task for both admin and customer then create a common helper for commonly usable functions.

My suggestion is you have to follow highly organized and decoupled modularity, you can follow the Hierarchical MVC architectural pattern for it.

You can refer [this](https://github.com/jlamim/ci3-hmvc) for HMVC in codeigniter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I will mark this as a accepted answer. But just give a few minute because sometimes I may get more answers from other.    I can create a common helper. **About display_product_list() : So you suggest that load database to a helper and write queries on helper?  Is it you mean?**

Comment: Yes, just create an instance of DB in helper and write commonly usable query there.It easy to access in your project.

Answer (score 1):

This all depends from you.
In my system I have a controllers + one model for every controller.
Remeber that you can use many models from controller.

If you have for example controller PageController you can still load ex pages_models or any other.

For login purposes I can recommend **ready module called Ion_Auth** - and you have all the controllers/models/views/languages inside, of course you can customize it also. Take a look at:
http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/
https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Ad. question 2:
For **PayPal** is also a module/plugin:
https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-codeigniter

Hope that helps.